# How to check error when validating jwt token using validate-jwt (Previously: How to use a custom built jwt in validate-jwt?)

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-api-management

I try to limit access to a REST API using a JWT token using the `validate-jwt` policy. Never did that before.

Here's my inbound policy (taken from the point **Simple token validation** [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies?redirectedfrom=MSDN#ValidateJWT)):

```
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" require-scheme="Bearer">
    <issuer-signing-keys>
        <key>{{jwt-signing-key}}</key>
    </issuer-signing-keys>
    <audiences>
        <audience>CustomerNameNotDns</audience>
    </audiences>
    <issuers>
        <issuer>MyCompanyNameNotDns</issuer>
    </issuers>
</validate-jwt>
```

Using [this generator](http://jwtbuilder.jamiekurtz.com/) I created a claim (I'm not sure whether I understood issuer and audience correctly):

```
{
    "iss": "MyCompanyNameNotDns",
    "iat": 1572360380,
    "exp": 2361278784,
    "aud": "CustomerNameNotDns",
    "sub": "Auth"
}
```

In the section **Signed JSON Web Token** I picked **Generate 64-bit key** from the combo box. The key that was generated I put in the place of **{{jwt-signing-key}}**.

Now, I'm trying to call the API using Postman. I add an "Authorization" header, and as the value I put "Bearer {{ JWT created by the [linked generator](http://jwtbuilder.jamiekurtz.com/) }}".

I get 401, JWT not present. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jim Xu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58620325/1693915) to encode the key as base64 string in the policy allowed me to get this far :-)

I set the **Ocp-Apim-Trace** parameter to true in order to debug it more closely. I followed the link provided in the response under **ocp-apim-trace-location**, and in the "on error" section I found the following message:

```
JWT Validation Failed: IDX10225: Lifetime validation failed. The token is missing an Expiration Time. Tokentype: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken'..
```

Which is funny, because I have set the Expiration Time... to 2099.

I changed it to a month from now and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

According to my research, If you use HS256  signing algorithms, the key must be provided inline within the policy in the base64 encoded form. In other words, we must encode the key as base64 string. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT)
[image]

My test steps are as below

1. Create Jwt token
   [image]
   [image]
2. Test
   a. If I directly provide the key in the policy, I get the 401 error
   [image]

[image]

b. If I encode the key as base64 string in the policy, I can call the api
[image]
[image]

Comment: I converted the string with `Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(` as you suggested, but I still get `401 Unauthorized` with message `Invalid JWT`.When looking at trace section in Azure Portal I learn under validate-jwt that `Expression was successfully evaluated.`.

Comment: Have you provided the subscription key?

Comment: I turned off the subscription key for this API.

Comment: If you do not add the policy, could you call the api?

Comment: Yes, without the validate-jwt policy the API works very good.

Comment: Could you please check if you use the same issuer audience and key in your policy and tool?

Comment: I checked and I'm using the same values issuer (string name of company), audience (also string name of company) in Policy as I do in [this tool](http://jwtbuilder.jamiekurtz.com/). Also use the same key as is generated.

Comment: @MauriceKlimek According to the details you provided, audience is customer name not company name

Comment: @MauriceKlimek Is that you use HS256 signing algorithms?

Comment: that is correct, audience is customer name, issuer is company name. And I use HS256 signing algorithms.

Comment: why Convert.ToBase64String required?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using "Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(", you can use this site https://www.base64encode.org/ and convert you Token secret key to Base64 string and put it direct as key on API Management.

It worked for me.