# APIM JWT Validate Policy Key Issuer Issue

Tags: azure-active-directory, jwt, azure-ad-b2c, azure-api-management, apim

I am using APIM to validate JWT Tokens and here is my policy looks

```
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
        <audience>68f3930e-0492-4642-8cd0-65d68a504dba</audience>
        <audience>7a20a24d-1bc7-4906-8dfc-c0e6dfd19d69</audience>
        <audience>ae901aaf-6bea-4e1b-902c-6851e4305b1b</audience>
        <audience>0d5b8f5e-4045-459c-99f1-a710ca8dd63e</audience>
        <audience>c37587ed-2974-4932-b87f-e51886ca378e</audience>
        <audience>2f96ac72-7887-4aa4-a02c-204288fe1ed8</audience>
        <audience>7c5dd291-edd7-4dc4-ad09-25ac006a0a42</audience>
    </audiences>
    <issuers>
        <issuer>https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TennatId}/v2.0/</issuer>
        <issuer>https://{Tennant}.b2clogin.com/38cf84e1-4cbb-4abb-8aa3-4c0f7107c585/v2.0/</issuer>
        <issuer>https://sts.windows.net/{TennatId}/</issuer>
    </issuers>
</validate-jwt>
```

I am specifying issuers so I can validate B2B and B2C JWT Tokens and also added Audience as well so it can validates the token generated by multiple applications. I am not specifying OpenId Config because there is explicit issuers are specified in my case.

I am getting this error

```
validate-jwt (-0.148 ms)
{
    "message": "JWT Validation Failed: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature.."
}
```

I tried to specify the Issuer keys like this which I am getting this way

```
1- https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/discovery/keys?appid={client_id}
2- https://{Tennant}.b2clogin.com/{tennant}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_si/discovery/v2.0/keys
```

I am retrieving multiple Kids and which I specified below but getting error on saving policy for "Not valid Base64 string"

```
 <issuer-signing-keys>
        <key>X5eXk4xyojNFum1kl2Ytv8dlNP4-c57dO6QGTVBwaNk</key>
        <key>Mr5-AUibfBii7Nd1jBebaxboXW0</key>
 </issuer-signing-keys>
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong in my case.

Answer (score 0):

> getting error on saving policy for "Not valid Base64 string"

You can use the `<issuer-signing-keys>` keys in Base64 format as `<key>@(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("signing-keys")))</key>`, please refer [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610203/how-to-check-error-when-validating-jwt-token-using-validate-jwt-previously-how?rq=2).  But symmetric keys are required to validate A128CBC-HS256, A192CBC-HS384, A256CBC-HS512 algorithms, as per [this ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validate-jwt-policy).

I have used below policy to validate jwt token using Azure AD without using any key.

```
<policies>
<inbound>
<base  />
<validate-jwt  header-name="Authorization"  failed-validation-httpcode="401"  failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid."  require-scheme="Bearer">
<openid-config  url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/.well-known/openid-configuration"  />
<audiences>
<audience>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</audience>
</audiences>
<issuers>
<issuer>https://sts.windows.net/{tenant_id}/</issuer>
</issuers>
</validate-jwt>
</inbound>
<backend>
<base  />
</backend>
<outbound>
<base  />
</outbound>
<on-error>
<base  />
</on-error>
</policies>
```

**Output**

[image]

Refer [SO Thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63700252/validate-multiple-issuers-in-azure-apim-policy) for validating multiple issuer and audiences.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as I mentioned in my question I want to validate both B2B and B2C JWT token so I cannot specify the openId-config because you can define either for B2B or B2C and once you define one of those like you specified for B2B it will only validates B2B tokens since its getting Issuer Keys from Open-Config for B2B only automatically. I also tried passing base64 one and it doesnot work

Comment: yes, you can specify both Open-Config like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63700252/validate-multiple-issuers-in-azure-apim-policy

Comment: Sure that make sense I can somhow workaround it by defining the products and using with choose statement in policy. Only issue is in my case I have kind of single product. But thanks for pointing it out I will see if I can hack it somehow